# Trying to Get Integer Separated by Space in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to enter integers separated by a space and then trying to retrieve them. As simple as that, but I am unable to do that.

So what I am trying to do is, First asking how many numbers a user would like to enter, he/she would enter the number and then would enter that amount of numbers with space in the middle.

After a user entered the numbers separated with space, I would just want to print them back.

### Proposed Output

```
How many numbers do you want to enter?

5

Please enter 5 integers seperated by a space

1 2 3 4 5

You entered:-

1
2
3
4
5
```

### This is what I did:-

```
int amountofnumbers;

Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner myinput2 = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
int amountofnumbers = myinput.nextInt();


System.out.println("Please enter" + amountofnumbers + "integers seperated by a space");
actualnumbers = myinput2.nextInt();

System.out.println("You entered:- ");
for (int i = 1; i <= amountofnumbers ; i++) 
{ 
    System.out.println(actualnumbers);
}
```

### Result

At the moment, it shows

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: Can you show what happens when you run it?

Comment: `String#split`?  Maybe even a new `Scanner` wrapping around the original input and using `Scanner#hasNextInt` and `Scanner#nextInt`....?

Comment: You should put `actualnumbers = myinput2.nextInt();` into a loop, since you're reading several numbers. Store into array & print out the array later.

Comment: @VineetRamachandran Yeah, but the OP needs to read a single line of text in one go...

Comment: You are reading your input only once and then printing the value 5 times. You probably need an array and a *better for loop*

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Vineet, I added this in the loop `System.out.println (myinput2.nextInt());`, and it worked!
`

Comment: @Steve - Also, you don't need 2 scanner instances. You can reuse the same instance as long as it points to the same stream

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to capture all five comma separated integers using:
`actualnumbers = myinput2.nextInt();` which will be actually reading only one `int` which in your case turns out to be `1`.

You need to read the integers either in a loop or in a String which you can split on space and then print the numbers. You do not need two scanners as well as mentioned by TheLostMind . It seems you want to do it in a loop then use the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int amountofnumbers;
        int[] actualnumbers;

        Scanner myinput = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
        amountofnumbers = myinput.nextInt();

        actualnumbers = new int[amountofnumbers];
        for(int index=0; index<amountofnumbers; index++)
        {
            System.out.println ("Please enter");
            actualnumbers[index] = myinput.nextInt();

        }
         myinput.close();
         System.out.println("You entered:");
        for(int enteredNumber : actualnumbers){
            System.out.println (enteredNumber) ;
        }
    }
```

And the output is:

`How many numbers do you want to enter?
3
Please enter
1
Please enter
2
Please enter
3
You entered:
1
2
3`

Comment: As TheLostMind mentioned, better to remove the second scanner. Also close the first one at the end.

Comment: Thanks, it just skipped my mind to close the scanner. I thought may be OP needs two scanners for some undisclosed reasons. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the input of the number array as String and divide them by split() function. Then, either print them or insert in the int array

```
public static void main( String[] argv ) throws Exception{

int amountofnumbers;

Scanner myinput = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner myinput2 = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to enter?");
amountofnumbers = myinput.nextInt();

try {
    int[] numbers = new int[amountofnumbers];

    System.out.println("Please enter " + amountofnumbers + " integer(s) seperated by a space");
    String actualnumbers = myinput2.nextLine();

    String[] amounts = actualnumbers.split(" ", amountofnumbers);
    if (amounts.length != amountofnumbers) {
        System.err.println("No of input should be: " + amountofnumbers);
        return;
    }
    for (int i=0; i<amounts.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(amounts[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("You entered:- ");
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length ; i++)  { 
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
    }
}
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    System.err.println("Only integer can be input");
}
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.err.println("No of input should be: " + amountofnumbers);
}

myinput.close();
myinput2.close();
}
```

Sample output:

```
How many numbers do you want to enter?
5
Please enter 5 integer(s) seperated by a space
1 2 3 4 5
You entered:- 
1
2
3
4
5
```